# Writing Tests for Slick Components

Tags: scala, slick

I'm currently working on improving test coverage in my app that uses Slick for connectivity to a MySQL database. In the past (my Java/Spring days), I have put the test inside a transaction and rolled back any changes on the database after the test was completed. Is there a way to accomplish the same functionality with Scala and Slick? If not, what options do I have for creating integration tests between my app and my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScalaQuery is the old Slick and you should be able to use the same techniuqe described in this thread.

Noitice the **withTransaction** and rollback.

[How do I rollback a session in ScalaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029096/how-do-i-rollback-a-session-in-scalaquery)

If there are any discrepancies between slick and ScalaQuery you may be able to find the updated usage now when you know what to look for.